# Reed Solomon Polynomial Generator

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, computer-science, finite-fields, coding-theory

I am developing a sample program to generate a 2D Barcode, using Reed-Solomon error correction codes. By going through this [article](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-coding), I am developing the program. But I couldn't understand how he generated the generator polynomial.

Can anybody explain how they generated the generator polynomial? Please guide me to complete this correction step.

Comment: Did you understand the calculations in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/40634/11619)? Reproducing those is doable in this space, but an example involving $GF(256)$ is a tall(er) order :-). Mind you, I don't like the article you linked to very much. Some of the terminology used there is a bit off me thinks. For example, I have never seen the term *error correction code words* used to mean the sequence of check symbols :-)

Comment: Ok I came to know the generator polynomial is G(x)=(x-α)(x-α2).....(x-αt) where t=N-K-1 after generating this polynomial in the same article there is a log and anti-log table giving the values of α till <a href="http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/log-antilog-table/"> α ^255</a>. Keep aside generator polynomial how to know the α value based on its power ...... I dont know may be i am asking very simple question as i am naive to this ...... thanks ....

Comment: I am in agreement with @JyrkiLahtonen that I don't like the article that you are using.  Not only does it use strange terminology, but a quick look shows that there are several mistakes as well.  For example, even the definition of the generator polynomial that you have copied from the article into your comment above is suspect.  I think that you need to find an article that will help you understand the concept of a finite field a little more than you seem to do, and I strongly recommend not using anything from thonky.com; look elsewhere.

Comment: Can anyone of you please suggest me an article/resource where i can find reed solomon in simple terms .....

Comment: I don't know, if my attempt answers your question at all, but I use it as a first iteration.
Unfortunately I cannot promise to give you several iterations per day, so look for other sources (and Dilip's and other posters' eventual answers). There is a lot of stuff to cover, if you want to understand the actual error correction algorithms. I won't take you the distance (it's almost a full course's worth of material), but would like to get you started. If you want me to work out the other toy example (links above), I can do that (hopefully some time tomorrow). @ping me!

Comment: Sure and Thank you so much ..... meanwhile i will try to understand the toy example you have given and try to implement......

Comment: Ahhhh..... After so many days i took pen and paper and did polynomial division.... it reminded my school days.... i really wanted to learn coding theory .........

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: For reed solomon error correction how can i select/compute the α value to substitute into generator polynomial. In the toy example you have selected the value as 2 over finite field 11. Now my problem finite field size is 256. Then how to go with α value ? can we assume any value to α and compute their exponents as specified in the example....

Comment: No. You have to be careful. Even in the toy example below I couldn't have used for example $\alpha=4$, because its powers would start repeating too soon ($4^5=1024\equiv1\pmod{11}$). Furthermore, when the size of the field is not a prime number, but a power of a prime number, then you cannot use an integer as $\alpha$. Instead you have to select $\alpha$ to be a root of a carefully selected polynomial. I will edit my answer, and try to give a bit more detail.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let me show a toy example of a case, where we can use $\alpha=2$. In the more general finite field we cannot think of $\alpha$ as having a numerical 'value'. I use the finite field $GF(11)$ that is isomorphic to the ring of residue classes of integers modulo 11. I assume that you are at least somewhat familiar with modular arithmetic. This way we can take a look at the use of the generator polynomial in encoding the message without having to worry about the construction of the finite field as well. Also the answer will be of a `reasonable' size :-)
$$
GF(11)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A=-1\},
$$
where $A$ stands for the residue class of $10\equiv-1\pmod{11}$. The Reed-Solomon codes use
the fact that the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of this (and any other) finite field
is cyclic, i.e. consists of powers of a carefully selected element $\alpha$. Trial and error shows that we can select $\alpha=2$, because $\alpha^0=1$, $\alpha^1=2$, $\alpha^2=4$,
$\alpha^3=8$, $\alpha^4=16= 5$, $\alpha^5=\alpha\cdot \alpha^4=2\cdot 5=10=-1$,
$\alpha^6=2\cdot A=20= 9$, $\alpha^7=2\cdot9=18= 7$, $\alpha^8=2\cdot7=14=3$, and
$\alpha^9=2\cdot3=6$. Note that i) I simply equate any two numbers that are congruent with each other modulo 11, because then the two numbers represent the same element of the field, ii) I won't get any new elements by continuing, because $\alpha^{10}=2\cdot6=12=1=\alpha^0$, so the powers of $\alpha$ repeat starting from the tenth power. A similar thing happens with all the finite fields.

In this toy example I describe the encoding procedure using an RS-code with alphabet $GF(11)$ that has $r=4$ check symbols (IOW the code will have minimum distance $r+1=5$ and
thus be able to correct up to $t=2$ errors, because $2t+1=5$. This type of an RS-code can
carry a message consisting of up to six ($6=11-1-r$) symbols $m_0,m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5$
that are all elements of the field $GF(11)$. We could agree to use shorter messages, but
this time I go with the maximum. The encoding process expands this message into a longer sequence $c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_9$ of ten symbols from the field $GF(11)$.  In order to make the algebra easier to describe we view such sequences as a polynomials. So let $x$ be an unknown, and write
$$m(x)= m_0+m_1x+m_2x^2+m_3x^3+m_4x^4+m_5x^5$$
and
$$c(x)= c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+\cdots+c_9x^9.$$
For the error-correction to work as described, we must make sure that the polynomial $c(x)$ represents a valid codeword, so it has to be a multiple of the generator polynomial
of degree $r=4$
$$
g(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^4)=(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-5).
$$
As an exercise you are invited to verify that after expanding this product and reducing all the coefficients modulo 11 you get
$$
g(x)=x^4+3x^3+5x^2+8x+1.
$$
There are two common ways of turning the message polynomial $m(x)$ to a codeword $c(x)$
that is always divisible by $g(x)$. The simplest way (algebraically) is to declare
$$
c(x)=g(x)m(x).
$$
This is what is known (see e.g. the Wikipedia page) as non-systematic encoding, so e.g. the said Wikipedia page and
[Dilip's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40634) denote this polynomial 
$c_{nonsys}(x)$. For example, if the message sequence that you want to encode is
$(m_0,m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5)=(3,0,0,0,0,1)$, the message polynomial is $m(x)=3+x^5$, and
$$
c_{nonsys}(x)=g(x)m(x)=g(x)(x^5+3)=3 + 2x + 4x^2 + 9x^3 + 3x^4 + x^5 + 8x^6 + 5x^7 + 
    3x^8 + x^9,
$$
so the encoded message is the sequence $(3,2,4,9,3,1,8,5,3,9)$.

For practical reasons engineers often prefer to use so called systematic encoding. Dilip's answer (linked to above) gives you the following recipe: Compute the polynomial
$x^rm(x)=x^4(x^5+3)=x^9+3x^4$, and then compute the remainder, when you divide this
polynomial with the generator polynomial $g(x)$. The answer is $r(x)=4x+4x^2+x^3$.
Thus the polynomial
$$
c_{sys}(x)=x^4 m(x)-r(x)=x^9+3x^4-x^3-4x^2-4x=7x+7x^2+Ax^3+3x^4+x^9
$$
is also divisible by $g(x)$. This time the encoded sequence is thus $(0,7,7,A,3,0,0,0,0,1)$. The reason why this is called systematic is that you see the
payload message sequence $(3,0,0,0,0,1)$ at the end.

=======================

Added: Constructing finite fields of characteristic two.

Here we need more algebra. The field $GF(256)$ is of characteristic two. In other words, every element $\beta \in GF(256)$ satisfies the relation $\beta+\beta=0$. To give you the idea I first describe, how you get a smaller field $GF(8)$. This is just to save space.
The idea is that we want to list the elements of this field as powers of a special element
$\alpha$ the same way we used powers of two in the earlier example. A field will always have special elements $0,1$, so to get to eight elements we want the field to look like
$$
GF(8)=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5,\alpha^6\}.
$$
In the above example of $GF(11)$ the powers of $\alpha$ started repeating after the tenth power ($2^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$). Here we want the powers to start repeating starting from the seventh ($7=8-1$, $10=11-1$), so we want $\alpha^7=1$. Furthermore, we want to be able to add elements of the field together, like $\alpha^3+\alpha^5$ or $1+\alpha^4$ should be one of the elements. The way to achieve this is to declare that $\alpha$ is a root of certain carefully chosen polynomial equation. This time we choose the equation 
$$\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0.$$
IOW, $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x)=x^3+x+1$.

How does that help? The idea is that then we can calculate with powers of $\alpha$, and always use that equation $p(\alpha)=0$ to reduce to lower powers of $\alpha$. This is much the same way as when you multiply complex numbers together, you use the equation $i^2=-1$, e.g. $(2+i)(3+i)=6+2i+3i+i^2=6+5i+i^2=6+5i-1=5+5i$. Only this time the equation only begins to help, when we reach the third power. Here 
$$
\alpha^3=\alpha^3+0=\alpha^3+p(\alpha)=\alpha^3+\alpha^3+\alpha+1=1+\alpha,
$$
because $\alpha^3+\alpha^3=0$. Let's see what happens, when we reduce the powers of $\alpha$ using this relation. In the last column of the following table I always
list the fully reduced version of that power of $\alpha$.
$$
\eqalign{
\alpha^0&=&&=1,\\
\alpha^1&=&&=\alpha,\\
\alpha^2&=&&=\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^3&=&&=1+\alpha,\\
\alpha^4&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^3=\alpha(1+\alpha)&=\alpha+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^5&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^4=\alpha(\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha^2+\alpha^3=\alpha^2+(1+\alpha)&=1+\alpha+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^6&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3=
\alpha+\alpha^2+(1+\alpha)&=1+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^7&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^6=\alpha(1+\alpha^2)=\alpha+\alpha^3=\alpha+(1+\alpha)&=1.
}$$
Here the last row was in a way superfluous, but I wanted to show you that this choice of the polynomial $p(x)$ leads to the desired conclusion that the powers of $\alpha$ start repeating after the seventh. Notice how a new line always depends on the preceding one, and how
the relation $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$ is applied as many times as necessary to get rid of all the cubic terms and higher.

Now you should notice that the end results in the last column contain all the quadratic polynomials of the form $b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2$, where all the coefficients $b_i,i=0,1,2$ are bits, i.e. elements of the set $\{0,1\}$. That this worked out in this way is kind of a miracle, but it happened, because we were smart in choosing the polynomial $p(x)$. Notice that $p(x)$ is of degree three, and $8=2^3$. Further notice that we can choose to represent
the elements of $GF(8)$ in two ways: either as a power of $\alpha$ or as a quadratic polynomial of $\alpha$. Which do we use? Depends on what we want to do! If we want to **add**
two elements of the field, we first switch to the quadratic polynomial form, so for example
$$
\alpha^3+\alpha^5=(1+\alpha)+(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=(1+1)+(\alpha+\alpha)+\alpha^2=\alpha^2.
$$
On the other hand, if we want to **multiply** two elements of the field, we simply use the
fact that the powers start repeating after the seventh, so $\alpha^6\cdot\alpha^4=\alpha^{10}=
\alpha^{7}\cdot\alpha^3=1\cdot\alpha^3=\alpha^3$. Or, if the elements are given in the
quadratic polynomial form, then we read the table from right to left e.g.
$$
(1+\alpha)(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha^3\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha^8=\alpha\cdot\alpha^7=\alpha.
$$
Observe that addition of two quadratic polynomials
$$
(a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2)+(b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2)=(c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2)
$$
amounts to (because of the $\beta+\beta=0$ rule) bitwise XORing of the bit strings, or
$c_0c_1c_2=(a_0a_1a_2)$^$(b_0b_1b_2)$, if I remember the correct C-notation.

For these reasons I keep two look up tables at hand, when I implement a finite field of characteristic two in a program. One to convert the powers $\alpha^i$ to low degree polynomials, and another to go to the reverse direction.

Ok, so that was $GF(8)$, but you want $GF(256)$, where $256=2^8$. This time the field should look like
$$
GF(256)=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\ldots,\alpha^{254}\}.
$$
Now the powers of $\alpha$ start repeating starting from the $255^{th}$, so $\alpha^{255}=1$.
Instead of quadratic polynomials we now end up using the representation in the form
$$
b_0+b_1\alpha+b_2\alpha^2+\cdots+b_7\alpha^7
$$
in terms of $8$ bits $b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_7$. In other words, a single byte will represent an element of this field in the 'additive' form. How do we build the conversion table? To do that we need a suitable polynomial $p(x)$. This time $p(x)$ must be of degree 8. The most common choice is
$$
p(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1.
$$
The page that you linked to seems to be using this. The replacement rule that we get out of this is $\alpha^8=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1$. You can use this relation to get rid of
all the eighth powers (and higher!) of $\alpha$. This time the table would have 255 rows, so I hope that you understand, why I won't reproduce it here. Your link seems to have that table.

For a list of other possible polynomials see [this link](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/primitive-polynomial-table.txt). They give some further links there, too. The links from your other questions lead to some hopefully useful C-code.

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer.  I answered a different question on how to compute the coefficients of $g(x)$ which is what I thought Sunny was asking about with "But i couldn't understand how he generated the Generator Polynomial."  As you said in your later comment on the question, _why_ the generator polynomial enables you to correct $t$ errors is a much deeper question that will take a lot longer to answer.

Comment: @Jykri Lahtonen: Thanks for the detailed answer. Able to reproduce the exponent to value tables with the given primitive polynomial over finite field 255.But not able to understand how we selected the primitive polynomial i will try to dig down more than that and will ask if still i have any doubts.....

Comment: Will give Bounty to this answer after 23 hours... ;)

Comment: @Sunny: People look up those polynomials from tables. And there's a reason for that! The theory proving that they exist is not too demanding, but finding them is a lot of work.

Comment: @Sunny Jyrki Lahtonen has added enough material to his answer that I wish I could add another upvote!  I will add that the two tables he refers to as being on hand are the log table and antilog table.  The _antilog_ table is the one Jyrki has constructed in his answer:  it answers the question "What is the polynomial corresponding to $\alpha^i$?"  Writing the right hand entries as $100$, $010$, $001$, $110$, $011$, $111$, $101$ and sorting on those, so that the $7$-th item (corresponding to $111$) in the table is $5$ meaning $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 = \alpha^5$ is the _log_ table.

Comment: This answer's almost like a survey paper/field guide... too bad I can't give another upvote.

Comment: Sorry guys, may be I got carried away a bit...?

Comment: Gee, why are you apologizing? It actually sucks that this answer can't get more upvotes... we should be thanking you profusely for this work!

Comment: @Jykri: I found one thing to generate the log and antilog table. I think the primitive polynomial has been converted to a formula which is like this.

For GF(255) to generate the table:
primitive=285;
size=256;
x=1;
For index in 0 to size-1:
   table[index]=x;
   x=x*2; // Multiply X by 2
   if x >= size:
       x^=primitive;// x=x (Power)285
       x&=size-1;// x=x bitwiseand 255

Resulting the same table. How this Polynomial got converted into this formula.

Comment: @Sunny: Sounds correct. Although I prefer to think of it as "ShiftLeft one bit position" as opposed to "Multiply by 2". The end result is, of course, the same. This is because even though they are presented as bytes/words, I don't think of elements of finite fields as integers at all. Mind you, it is $GF(256)$, don't forget that zero is also an element of this field.

Comment: @Sunny: Sorry, I did not notice your last question. The primitive polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ has $100011101$ as its string of coefficients. If you interpret that string of bits first as a word, and then that word as an integer, you get $2^8+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^0=285$. While carrying out the arithmetic above, we always replace $\alpha^8$ with $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1$. So that code snippet tests, whether the bit at position 8 is 'ON' by testing, whether the result is at least 256 (in the usual interpretation of a word as an integer). If 'yes', then we need to do that replacement.

Comment: I'm studying Finite groups and fields too, why in $GF(11)$ we could pick $\alpha$ as a number (being precise: $\alpha = 2$) and in $GF(8) = GF(2^3)$ we couldn't?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana: In some sense that depends on what you accept as a number :-) I loosely called $2$ a number in $GF(11)$  because I assumed that the asker would be familiar with the usual modular arithmetic of integers. When we go outside the world of $GF(p)$, $p$ a prime number, we need operations other than those provided by the modular arithmetic of integers, and I chose to make a distinction for pedagogical reasons. Sorry about not making that clear.

Comment: No, it's perfectly ok, yours was a marvelous answer! So, for example, in $GF(2^3) = GF(8)$ I can't find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha = 2$ or something similar? I'm "limited" to call my primitive root just $\alpha$? And is also the same for the other elements? I can't find some sort of "numerical equivalent" to them, I'm "limited" to the polynomial and exponential representations... Am I right?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana: I think it is simplest to just call it $\alpha$. We can get $GF(8)$ as a quotient ring of for example the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ where $\zeta$ is a seventh complex root of unity. But that way of looking at it is not at all useful for the purposes of doing $GF(8)$ arithmetic on a computer. On the contrary I think :-)

Comment: What if, at some time, you want to know which is the value of $\alpha$? Without expressing it in function of the other terms of the primitive polynomial of course

Answer (score 10):

Taking a special case of more general results, the generator polynomial of a 
cyclic $(n, n-2t)$ Reed-Solomon code over GF$(q)$, the finite field of $q$ elements,
is of the form
$$g(x) = g_0 + g_1x + \cdots + g_{2t}x^{2t} = (x-\alpha)(x - \alpha^2)\cdots (x-\alpha^{2t})$$ 
where $n$ is the number of symbols in a codeword, $t$ is the number of errors 
that can be corrected, and $\alpha$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity in the field.
In OP Sunny's special case, $q = 2^8 = 256$, $n = 255$ and $\alpha$ is a primitive element
of the field.  The elements of GF$(256)$ can be stored as $8$-bit bytes, and addition
in the field is the bit-by-bit Exclusive OR operation which is typically included
as a machine instruction on most processors.  Also, we can replace the minus signs in the above expression by plus signs since addition and subtraction are the same operation in any GF$(2^n)$.

OP Sunny's question seems to be: how do I compute the coefficients 
$g_i, 0 \leq i \leq 2t$?  The obvious answer is of course to multiply
the given factors together (which is what the article that he refers
to tells him to do), but since he seems to be unsure about how
to do this, here is an iterative procedure for it.

Suppose that the
coefficients are to be stored in a $(2t+1)$-byte array `g` with `g[i]` 
storing $g_i$, with `g[0]` initialized to $1$ and all other `g[i]` to $0$.
The elements $\alpha, \alpha^2,\cdots, \alpha^{2t}$ are stored in a $2t$-byte
array `alpha` with `alpha[i]` storing $\alpha^i$.  Assume that we have a
program `mult(x,y)` that takes two bytes $x$ and $y$ representing elements
of GF$(256)$ as input and returns the byte
value of the product of $x$ and $y$ in GF$(256)$. Then, the coefficients
$g_i$ are obtained in `g` via the following calculation:

```
for i = 1 step 1 until 2t do
     begin
     for j = 2t step -1 until 1 do
           begin
           g[j] = mult(g[j], alpha[i]) XOR g[j-1]
           end
     g[0] = mult(g[0]), alpha[i])
     end
```

This seems to be getting off-topic a bit for math.SE but I suspect 
that the folks on the StackOverflow.SE etc are not too familiar with
finite field arithmetic and the likes.