# How do i calculate a multiplication table for GF(8)?

Tags: finite-fields

Could you please provide the steps involved in calculating a multiplication table for GF(8)?

Comment: At the risk of blowing my own trumpet: a method (particularly suited for computer implementation) is described in the latter half of my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76045/11619).

Answer (score 6):

Take an irriducibile polynomial of degree $3$ over the field $\Bbb F_2$ with two elements, e.g. $P(X)=X^3+X+1$. Then you know that
$$
\Bbb F_8=\Bbb F_2[X]/(P(X))
$$
and that its 8 elements are represented by the 8 polynomials of degree $\leq2$. Thus you can construct the multiplication of $\Bbb F_8$ simply by multiplying these polynomials and taking the result modulo $P(X)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. What i do not understand is that in the text book i have the entry for a multiplication of 2(010) and 4(100) as 3 in GF(8). Could you explain in this context?

Comment: I am not sure what you (or the textbook) mean with that notation.

Comment: Okay maybe i m gonna copy paste a link which shows something similar happening.Here it is : http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/galois3.pl

Comment: @phoenix: Looks like "010" represents $0\cdot\tau^2 + 1\cdot\tau + 0\cdot1$, and "100" represents $1\cdot\tau^2 + 0\cdot\tau + 0\cdot1$.

Comment: As Andrea says, the elements of the field are (represented by) the polynomials of degree at most 2. Your source chooses a different representation; the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is represented by the bit-string $abc$ (or maybe $cba$, I didn't read closely enough to tell).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap...probably because if i multiply the two of them using the terms you said, i get x^3 which is not permissible here since the max degree would be 2. am i right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes i think you are correct