# How to find minimal polynomial for an element in $\mbox{GF}(2^m)$?

Tags: finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

I'm new to this Finite field theory. Someone please explain how minimal polynomials are generated for each element in GF(2^m). I searched in the website but I'm not getting any clue.

Comment: In which way is your finite field given? How do you do computations in it? (e.g. polynomial representation, cyclic,...)

Comment: I'm going through BCH codes for error detection and correction. To construct generator polynomial I need minimal polynomials of all the elements in the GF field. I'm stuck at this point...

Comment: Still, my question remains, how do you compute in $GF(2^m)$. Do you see it as the set of polynomials of degree less than $m$ over $GF(2)$ and do computations modulo a polynomial of order $m$, do you see it as a cyclic group generated by a primitive element $\alpha$ and having rules on how to add $\alpha^i + \alpha^j$ or do you have another, different way to do it. Depending on which, the answer to your question also differs.

Comment: Yeah, it is a set of polynomials over GF(2^m) and taking modulo with a polynomial.

Comment: If it's polynomials (or, rather, cosets of polynomials), then surely they have coefficients in $GF(2)$.

Comment: After studying my answer, for extra credit, you should find the minimal polynomials of $\gamma^3$ and $\gamma^5$, both from $GF(2^4)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) for the field tables. There will be a surprise with $\gamma^5$. Examine the resulting system to gain a bit of familiarity.

Comment: I added a couple of comments to Jyrki Lahtonen's answer.

Comment: Wiki article includes an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code#Example), but not an optimized way to implement it.

Answer (score 16):

This isn't too difficult because we only need methods from linear algebra. Let me do an example. I pick the field $GF(2^5)$ because for smaller fields I know the answer by heart, and I would fall back on ad hoc tricks rather than the general method.

Let $\alpha$ be a zero of the irreducible polynomial $x^5+x^2+1$. The task I assign to myself is to find the minimal polynomial of $\beta=\alpha^3$. From general theory we know that the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ has degree at most five (actually we can immediately see that it will be exactly five, but I try to avoid special knowledge here). So let's compute the powers $\beta^i, i\le 5$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta^0&=&&=1,\\
\beta^1&=&&=\alpha^3,\\
\beta^2&=\alpha^6=\alpha\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha(\alpha^2+1)&&=\alpha^3+\alpha,\\
\beta^3&=\alpha^3(\alpha^3+\alpha)=\alpha^6+\alpha^4&&=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha,\\
\beta^4&=\alpha^7+\alpha^6+\alpha^4=\alpha^6+\alpha^2&&=\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha,\\
\beta^5&=\alpha^6+\alpha^5+\alpha^4&&=\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1.
\end{aligned}
$$
At this point we can set up a linear system for the unknowns $c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_5$ and find a solution of the system
$$
c_0+c_1\beta+c_2\beta^2+c_3\beta^3+c_4\beta^4+c_5\beta^5=0
$$
by plugging in the values of the powers $\beta^i$ and then set the coefficients of all the powers of $\alpha$ to zero (the powers $1,\alpha,\cdots,\alpha^4$ are linearly independent (because $4<m=5$) so this is valid.
We get
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
c_0+c_5&=&0,\\
c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5&=&0,\\
c_4+c_5&=&0,\\
c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5&=&0,\\
c_3+c_5&=&0.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Note: One term was missing from the second equation. Fixing the answer as well.

This is an underdetermined homogeneous system, so it has non-trivial solutions. The lowest degree one gives the minimal polynomial (if the solution space has dimension $>1$ then you set undetermined coefficients to zero starting from the highest). I am sure you learned to handle these in linear algebra. So I go ad hoc at this point, and "guess" that $c_5=1$. The equations involving only two unknowns then immediately yield $c_0=c_3=c_4=1$. The remaining equations then imply $c_2=1$ and $c_1=0$. This means that $\beta$ satisfies the equation
$$
1+\beta^2+\beta^3+\beta^4+\beta^5=0,
$$
and its minimal polynomial is then
$$
m(\beta,x)=m_3(x)=1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5.
$$

Comment: How does it follow that $\alpha\cdot\alpha^5 = \alpha(\alpha^2 + 1)$?  Are you falling back on special knowledge or am I missing something?

Comment: @MrZander We started by assuming that $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^5+x^2+1$. Therefore $\alpha^5=\alpha^2+1$.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Thank you, that clears it up.

Comment: Rather then guessing that $c_5$ =1, note that $c_0$ = 1 because otherwise the equation could be written as $B (c_1 + c_2 B + c_3 B^2 + \dots) $ which wouldn't be a minimal polynomial. Since $c_0$ = 1, the first equation only has one unknown, in this case $c_5$ .

Comment: @Les You are right. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: @rcgldr The decision to use $\beta=\alpha^3$ was made simply because it was the first element that occurred to me. Yes, I also know that it is relevant to anyone working on BCH-codes :-) You may consider undeleting your answer!

Comment: For others reading this, think of $c_0$ as $c_0\ B^0\ (B^0 = 1)$. The first equation has coefficients $c_0 + c_5$ since $B^0,B^5$ include a factor of $\alpha^0 =1$. The second equation has $c_2 + c_3 + c_4 + c_5$ since $B^2, B^3,B^4,B^5$ include a factor of $\alpha^1$. The third equation has $c_4 + c_5$ since $B^4, B^5$ include a factor of $\alpha^2$, The forth equation is for the $B^i$'s that include a factor of $\alpha^3$. The fifth equation is for the $B^i$'s that include a factor of $\alpha^4$.

Comment: @Les - since the answer was updated, I deleted my prior comment and added a new one. I will delete this comment later.

Answer (score 4):

The OP's comment states the goal here is to generate the minimum polynomial for a BCH code. I have an old program that does a brute force search, similar to the example shown in the wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code#Example

Using GF(2^5) based on $x^5+x^2+1$, $\alpha=x+0 =$ hex 02, with code length n = 31, message length k and distance d for a code BCH(n,k,d).

Powers of $\alpha$ (hex 02) from 0 to 30 in GF(2^5), shown as hex:

```
01 02 04 08 10 05 0a 14
0d 1a 11 07 0e 1c 1d 1f
1b 13 03 06 0c 18 15 0f
1e 19 17 0b 16 09 12
```

A list of minimum polynomials with 1 bit coefficients otherwise under GF(2^5) for the 30 powers of $\alpha$ where $m_i(\alpha^i)\ mod\ (x^5+x^2+1) = 0$. Each of these can be found using the method shown in Jyrki Lahtonen's answer, or by a brute force search in the range $x^5+1$ to $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

m1,m2,m4,m8,m16 = $x^5+x^2+1$
m3,m6,m12,m17,m24 = $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$
m5,m9,m10,m18,m20 = $x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$
m7,m14,m19,m25,m28 = $x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1$
m11,m13,m21,m22,m26 = $x^5+x^4+x^3+x+1$
m15,m23,m27,m29,m30 = $x^5+x^3+1$

lcm(...) is the least common multiple for the list of $m_i$'s.

1 bit correction: BCH(31,26,3) => lcm(m1,m2) = 
$m1 = x^5+x^2+1$

2 bit correction: BCH(31,21,5) => lcm(m1,m2,m3,m4) = 
$m1\ m3 = x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^6+x^5+x^3+1$

3 bit correction: BCH(31,16,7) => lcm(m1,m2,...m6) = 
$m1\  m3\  m5 = x^{15}+x^{11}+x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^5+x^3+x^2+x^1+1$

5 bit correction: BCH(31,11,11) => lcm(m1,m2,...m10) = 
$m1\ m3\ m5\ m7 = x^{20}+x^{18}+x^{17}+x^{13}+x^{10}+x^9+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^2+1$

7 bit correction: BCH(31,6,15) => lcm(m1,m2,...m14) = 
$m1\ m3\ m5\ m7\ m11 =$
 $x^{25}+x^{24}+x^{21}+x^{19}+x^{18}+x^{16}+x^{15}+x^{14}+x^{13}+x^{11}+x^9+x^5+x^2+x+1$

15 bit correction: BCH(31,1,31) => lcm(m1,m2,...m30) = 
$m1\ m3\ m5\ m7\ m11\ m15 =$
$x^{30}+x^{29}+x^{28}...+x^2+x+1$ 
There are only two valid codes, all 0 bits or all 1 bits.

---

A common example of BCH code is for some types of ECC memory, which use a shortened BCH(127,120,3) code based on GF(2^7) plus a parity bit used to prevent a single bit correction if the number of error bits is even, such as 2, 64 bits of data, 7 bits for the BCH code, 1 bit for the parity, for a total of 72 bits. Since it's a single bit correction, the BCH generator polynomial will be the same as the field polynomial, such as $x^7+x+1$.

Answer (score 3):

The conjugates of an element $\alpha$ of GF[$2^k$] are $\{\alpha^{(2^i)},\;i\geq 0 \}$.
This set contains at most $k$ distinct elements-- let them be $\beta_1,\ldots ,\beta_j$.  The minimal polynomial is
$$
p_\alpha(x)=\prod_{i=1}^j (x-\beta_i).
$$