# How to find minimal polynomial if we know some root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, minimal-polynomials

So I tried to ask this question about two days ago, but no one could help me and I was wrong with some terminology, and my question was deleted.
Im studied abstract algebra and trying to solve some tasks.

So I have an polynomial $X^5+X^4+X^3+X+1$ with coefficients from $F_2[x]$, we know that a - is some root of this polynomial. I have to find minimal polynomial for $a^3+a^2+a$.
So I know that $F_2/f(x)$ isomorphic to $F_32$, (as our poly has no roots in $f2$, and deg($f$) = 5)

So if Im not wrong the next step is to search for ratios on a (that is, express the various degrees of a through smaller degrees)(for example we can put a in our poly and try to make something out)
and then somehow find this minimal poly

So I have problems with

1. Am I right?
2. How to find ratios on a
3. How it is related to minimal poly for $a^3+a^2+a$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find minimal polynomial for an element in $\mbox{GF}(2^m)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232179/how-to-find-minimal-polynomial-for-an-element-in-mboxgf2m) + "$f(x)$ has no roots in $F$" does not imply "$f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$"; only the latter is equivalent to "$F[x]/(f)$ is a field".

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Yes f(x) is irreducable over F!
Yes the linked question is similar to my, but i have some questiion,
In their case he is trying to find minimal poly for B = a^3
If im not wrong i have to take B as a^3+a^2+a?
and compute B^0, B^1, B^2......?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say. You'll have to calculate at most the fifth power of $B$, and then construct a nontrivial linear combination of the powers that equals $0$ (say, using Gaussian elimination). Please surround the $\TeX$ formulae with dollar signs (see [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) in your further questions.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Thanks a lot!!!! You really helped me!