# Example of Linear System of Polynomials over finite field

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

I'm trying to find any system of polynomial over finite field (solvable in $K[x]_{m(x)}$)
with characteristic two. I want please any example of $a_{ij}$ and $b_k$

$$a_{11}(x)*p+a_{12}(x)*q+a_{13}(x)*r = b_1(x)$$
$$a_{21}(x)*p+a_{22}(x)*q+a_{23}(x)*r = b_2(x)$$
$$a_{31}(x)*p+a_{32}(x)*q+a_{33}(x)*r = b_3(x)$$

where $p,q$ and $r$ are the variables and the coefficients of every polynomial $a_{ij}$ are in $K[x]_{m(x)}$ with $K=\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: By $K[x]_{m(x)}$ do you mean $K[x]/(m(x))$?

Comment: yes, ring of residues classes getting the irreductible polynomial $m(x)$ in $K[x]$

Comment: Just as I suspected!  Thanks!

Comment: The ring $K[x]/\langle m(x)\rangle$ is a field, so the methods from basic linear algebra work. Gaussian elimination, i.e. putting the matrix in reduced row echelon form. What do you mean by *fraction parts* here? There are no fractions in $K[x]/\langle m(x)\rangle$.

Comment: For example when $K=\Bbb{F}_2$ and $m(x)=x^3+x+1$, you have
$x^5\equiv x^2+x+1\pmod{m(x)}$. Because 
$$x^2(x^2+x+1)=x^4+x^3+x^2=(x+1)m(x)+1\equiv 1\pmod{m(x)}$$ we can conclude that
$$\frac1{x^2+x+1}=\frac1{x^5}=x^2.$$ Mind you sticking to $x$ does confuse many students here. It is better to think in terms of the coset $\alpha=x+\langle m(x)\rangle$. This is just an entity that happens to be zero of $m(x)$, i.e. we have $m(\alpha)=0$. The arithmetic is then much like that of, say, $\beta=\root3\of 2$. You operate with that applying $\beta^3=2$ where appropriate. Same here with $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give an example over $\Bbb{F}_8=K[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$.
First let me shamelessly copy the following relevant table from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76136/11619). Here $\alpha=x+\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ is trivially a zero of the polynomial $m(x)=x^3+x+1$ that is
irreducible in $K[x]$. See the latter half of that other answer for more details.
$$
\eqalign{
\alpha^0&=&&=1,\\
\alpha^1&=&&=\alpha,\\
\alpha^2&=&&=\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^3&=&&=1+\alpha,\\
\alpha^4&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^3=\alpha(1+\alpha)&=\alpha+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^5&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^4=\alpha(\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha^2+\alpha^3=\alpha^2+(1+\alpha)&=1+\alpha+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^6&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3=
\alpha+\alpha^2+(1+\alpha)&=1+\alpha^2,\\
\alpha^7&=&\alpha\cdot\alpha^6=\alpha(1+\alpha^2)=\alpha+\alpha^3=\alpha+(1+\alpha)&=1.
}$$
The above table show all the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{F}_8$, and you see that the multiplicative group is cyclic of order seven (as promised by the general theory). I very much prefer to use $\alpha$ here in place of $x$. This is becaus once we go to the quotient field of $K[x]$, $x$ stops being a free variable.

Let's "randomly" pick the 3x3 system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrcrcl}
\alpha x_1&+&&&\alpha^2x_3&=&1,\\
x_1&+&x_2&+&\alpha x_3&=&0,\\
(1+\alpha)x_1&+&\alpha x_2&&&=&\alpha.
\end{array}\right.
$$
The matrix of coefficients is
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha&0&\alpha^2\\
1&1&\alpha\\
1+\alpha&\alpha&0
\end{array}\right).
$$
We see that
$$
\det A=\alpha^3+\alpha^3+\alpha^2(\alpha+1)=0+\alpha^3+\alpha^2=1+\alpha+\alpha^2\neq0,
$$
so $A$ is non-singular, and we know that the system has a unique solution. We find this with the usual method of finding the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix (thereby making the calculation of the determinant unnecessary).
First I permute the rows to get a $1$ to the upper left
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&\alpha&0\\
\alpha&0&\alpha^2&1\\
1+\alpha&\alpha&0&\alpha
\end{array}\right).
$$
Adding (we are in characteristic two, so addition and subtraction are the same operation) the indicated multiples of the first row to the other two gives
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&\alpha&0\\
0&\alpha&\alpha^2+\alpha^2&1\\
0&\alpha+(1+\alpha)&\alpha(1+\alpha)&\alpha
\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&\alpha&0\\
0&\alpha&0&1\\
0&1&\alpha+\alpha^2&\alpha
\end{array}\right).
$$
To get a $1$ at position $(2,2)$ I divide the second row by $\alpha$. From the table we see that $1/\alpha=\alpha^7/\alpha=\alpha^6=1+\alpha^2$, so I multiply it with $1+\alpha^2$, and get
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&\alpha&0\\
0&1&0&1+\alpha^2\\
0&1&\alpha+\alpha^2&\alpha
\end{array}\right).
$$
Pivoting the second column amounts to adding the second row to the other two, so we get
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1+1&\alpha&1+\alpha^2\\
0&1&0&1+\alpha^2\\
0&1+1&\alpha+\alpha^2&\alpha+(1+\alpha^2)
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&\alpha&1+\alpha^2\\
0&1&0&1+\alpha^2\\
0&0&\alpha+\alpha^2&1+\alpha+\alpha^2
\end{array}\right).
$$
From the table we see that the $(3,3)$ entry $\alpha^2+\alpha=\alpha^4$.
Therefore its inverse is $1/\alpha^4=\alpha^7/\alpha^4=\alpha^3=1+\alpha$, so
I multiply the last row with $1+\alpha$. To do that I need to calculate the
product. Again I use the table heavily:
$$
(1+\alpha)(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=\alpha^3\cdot\alpha^5=\alpha^8=\alpha\cdot\alpha^7=\alpha,
$$
and get
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&\alpha&1+\alpha^2\\
0&1&0&1+\alpha^2\\
0&0&1&\alpha
\end{array}\right).
$$
Pivoting the last column then gives
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&1+\alpha^2+\alpha^2\\
0&1&0&1+\alpha^2\\
0&0&1&\alpha
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1+\alpha^2\\
0&0&1&\alpha
\end{array}\right).
$$
From this we can read the solution
$$
x_1=1,\quad x_2=1+\alpha^2,\quad x_3=\alpha.$$

I leave it as an exercise to check (by plugging them in) that this is, indeed, a solution. I did it, so you have to do it, too!

The key to the arithmetic is to use the table in both directions. Multiplication/division is easier, if you first convert everything to powers of $\alpha$. Addition is easier, if you first convert everything to low degree polynomials of $\alpha$ (here at most quadratic).