# Construct a 2-error correcting Reed-Solomon code over GF(11).

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I'am trying to construct a 2-error correcting Reed-Solomon code over GF(11). Cna anyone help me to start?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. What definitions are you starting with? Please add more details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Today is your lucky day. Somebody asked about Reed-Solomon codes here years ago, and I used an RS-code over GF(11) with minimum distance 5 as a toy example.

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76136/11619) for the details.