# Calculating the generator of a Finite Field

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, primitive-roots

I'm trying to understand how to compute the [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_(finite_field)) of a finite field.

$\alpha \in GF(q)$

so for example if I was working with $GF(2^8)$

I think I would need to find

$\alpha ^ {256-1} \equiv 1 (\mod 256)$

How do I calculate that?

Comment: How do you realize the field $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$?

Comment: @Moos I'm not sure what you mean by realize. I'm reading about Reed-Solomon error detection and `GF(2^8)` seems to be used in some of the documents I've found which describe the algorithm.

Comment: http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring10/cps296.3/finitefields.pdf

Comment: So your $GF(2^8)$ is $\Bbb F_2[X]/(p(X))$ for a suitable polynomial $p$ ... ?[

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  maybe I am missunderstanding galois fields. But I just thought that a galois field was a field with a finite number of elements. In my case, the integers from 0 to 255, with + and × in (mod 256). I'm not sure how polynomials come into this.

Comment: $GF(2^8)$ is _not_ " the integers from 0 to 255, with + and × in (mod 256)" which is $\mathbb Z_{256}$ or $\mathbb Z/256\mathbb Z$. I doubt that a CS course at Duke University claims what you say it does.

Comment: Yea I've most likely misunderstood something. What is $GF(2^8)$ then ?

Comment: The others got it right - the arithmetic of the field $GF(256)$ is not that of integers modulo $256$. That model only works for $GF(p)$, where $p$ is a prime number. At the risk of blowing my own trumpet... [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/76136/11619) I seek to describe what these fields and their arithmetic look like.